# Want to hide the div if sql value is 0 with c#, jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am creating a location management system using C#, SQL and ASP.NET. I want to hide the card div if either my home base location count, pouch count or bunker count is equal to 0 in my database and show all the locations when the value is < 0. Here's my code is below.

HTML

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.allItems)
    {


        \<div class="card" style="width: 50px;"\>
            \<div class="card-img-top" src="@item.ImageURL" alt="Card Image Cap"\>\</div\>
        \</div\>

        \<div class="card"\>
            \<div class="card-body"\>
                \<div class="card-img-top" src="@item.ImageURL" alt="Card Image Cap"\>\</div\>
                \<h5 class="card-title"\>\<p\>Test\</p\>@item.Name\</h5\>
                \<h6 class="card-title"\>@item.ItemType\</h6\>
                \<h6 class="card-title"\>@item.GroupType\</h6\>
                \<p class="homebase" style="color: black;"\>@item.HomebaseCount\</p\>
                \<p class="pouch" style="color: black;"\>@item.PouchCount\</p\>
                \<p class="bunker" style="color: black;"\>@item.BunkerCount\</p\>

                \<input type="text" class="textBoxHome defaultTextBox" /\>

            \</div\>
        \</div\>

    }

\</div\>
```

<script>

```
        $("#homebase").add("#bunker").add("#pouch").click(function () {
            $('.container-2').fadeTo(500, 1);
            $('.container-1').hide();
            $('.container-3').hide();
            $('.pouch').hide();
            $('.bunker').hide();
            $(function () {
                if ($('.homebase') === '0') {
                    $('.homebase').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.homebase').show();
                }
            });
        });
```

</script>

Answer (score 1):

**Hiding**

Hiding a `div` can be done with `style="display: none;"`. You want to do this on some condition.

Example for `HomeBaseCount` only:

```
<div class="card" @Html.Raw((item.HomebaseCount == 0 ? "style='display: none;'" : ""))
```

Because `style` is used, the HTML is rendered and you could make it visible with JavaScript later if you like.

**Not rendering the HTML**

If a `div` should not be rendered (no HTML for that `div` should be sent to the client), you can use

```
@if(item.HomebaseCount != 0 || ..)
{
    // your div
}
```

If all HTML between the braces of the `foreach` loop should not be rendered  you could also use a `.Where()` statement:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.allItems.Where(x => x. HomebaseCount != 0 || ..)
{
    // more divs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `if` validation before the div card

```
@if (item.HomebaseCount !== 0 || item.HomebaseCount !== 0) 
{
  <div class="card"\>
    @* code goes here *@
  </div\> 
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! How would I apply this to all the counts? So if HomebaseCount, PouchCount and BunkerCount are 0, don't show?

Comment: You could change the OR operator `||` to an AND operator `&&` and verify all counters you want

`item.HomebaseCount !== 0 && item.HomebaseCount !== 0 item.BunkerCount !== 0`